# Unhandled rejection TypeError: path.extname is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, path, bluebird

I am trying to write a function that goes trough the content of a directory and returns all the xml files inside the directory. So far I am able to return all the files in the directory (`console.log(files)` prints out an array of strings with the file names, but when I try to filter with the `path.extname` function I am getting:

> usr/local/Cellar/node/6.8.0/bin/node
>   /Users/shooshte/Sportradar/notThatKindOfPeon/bluebird.js Unhandled
>   rejection TypeError: path.extname is not a function
>       at /Users/shooshte/Sportradar/notThatKindOfPeon/bluebird.js:23:31
>       at Array.filter (native)
>       at /Users/shooshte/Sportradar/notThatKindOfPeon/bluebird.js:22:30
>       at tryCatcher (/Users/shooshte/Sportradar/notThatKindOfPeon/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/util.js:16:23)
>       at Promise._settlePromiseFromHandler (/Users/shooshte/Sportradar/notThatKindOfPeon/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:510:31)
>       at Promise._settlePromise (/Users/shooshte/Sportradar/notThatKindOfPeon/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:567:18)
>       at Promise._settlePromise0 (/Users/shooshte/Sportradar/notThatKindOfPeon/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:612:10)
>       at Promise._settlePromises (/Users/shooshte/Sportradar/notThatKindOfPeon/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:691:18)
>       at Promise._fulfill (/Users/shooshte/Sportradar/notThatKindOfPeon/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/promise.js:636:18)
>       at /Users/shooshte/Sportradar/notThatKindOfPeon/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/nodeback.js:42:21
>       at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:123:15)

This is my code:

```
const Promise = require('bluebird');
const fs = Promise.promisifyAll(require('fs'));
const path = require('path');

function getFileNames(path) {
  // Read content of path
  return fs.readdirAsync(path)
      // For every file in path
      .then(function(content) {
        // Filter out the directories
        return content.filter(function(file) {
          return fs.statSync(path + '/' + file).isDirectory();
        });
      })
      // For every directory
      .then(function(directories) {
        directories.map(function(directory) {
          // Read file in the directory
          fs.readdirAsync(path + '/' + directory + '/')
              .then(function(files) {
                // Filter out the XMLS
                return files.filter(function(file) {
                  return path.extname(file) == '.XML';
                });
                console.log(files);
              });
          });
        });
      }

getFileNames('./XML');
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're using `path` for two different things, and they're interfering with each other. You have a module global:

```
const path = require('path');
// ---^
```

...but then you *shadow* that with an argument:

```
function getFileNames(path) {
// -------------------^
```

So within `getFileNames`, the `path` identifier refers to that argument, not your global, and since it doesn't refer to the `path` module (from context, I'm guessing the `path` argument is a string), you don't have [`path.extname`](https://nodejs.org/api/path.html#path_path_extname_path).

Use different names.